# Proper usage for "ReactComponent as"

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use "[ReactComponent as](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs)" for adding SVG in my project with the below code, unfortunately, I am getting the same icon for both, like the second one is overriding the first one. both are alone working fine means at a time one in the project, am I missing anything?

```
import { ReactComponent as exitIcon } from '../images/exit_app.svg';
import { ReactComponent as solarIcon } from "../images/solar.svg";

export const ExitIcon = exitIcon;
export const SolarIcon = solarIcon;
```

In my component

```
import { SolarIcon, ExitIcon } from "../../icons/icons";
<SolarIcon />
<ExitIcon className={"icon exit-icon"} />
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, I found the solution.

It happened along with the icon itself which not exported properly.

when I open both SVG icons in an editor, it seems like id and/or mask are identical for both icons. I made it unique manually and saved it. after its working fine for me.

[image]